# Hide a band in stimulsoft report

Tags: stimulsoft

I have a mrt report with multiple bands,

Can I hide any of this bands on some condition ?

For example there is a string field in footerband and I want to hide this band if this field is empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Conditions for this.
There is a Component is Enabled option. You should disable it. After this if the Condition expression is true the component will be disabled.

Comment: The OP asks how to hide. Hidden and disabled are the same thing in Stimulsoft?

Comment: For my case I needed to hide or show two graphs depending on a parameter, they were inside a data source, so in my case I just used excluding conditions on both and overlapped both grapsh one over the other and shrunk the data source